# How can I embed an inline image to Mailgun in ASP.net Core app?

Tags: email, asp.net-core, inline, mailgun

I am trying to send an inline attached image with an email using Mailgun API but I don't know how could I solve it. Waht I know that I could somehow put something to the form but have not a a clue what. The raw image content? I suspect I also should change the content encoding to multipart form encoding.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any example in the net.

Could someone help me please?

Thanks in advance.
Gabriel

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("api:" + API_KEY)));

var form = new Dictionary<string, string>();
form["from"] = FROM;
form["to"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? email : name + "<" + email + ">";
form["subject"] = subject;
form["html"] = message;

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.mailgun.net/v2/" + DOMAIN + "/messages", new FormUrlEncodedContent(form));
```

Answer (score 4):

I could manage to solve it in this way:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("api:" + API_KEY)));

var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StringContent(FROM), "from");
content.Add(new StringContent(string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? email : name + "<" + email + ">"), "to");
content.Add(new StringContent(subject), "subject");
content.Add(new StringContent(message), "html");
var fileStream = new StreamContent(File.Open("./wwwroot/images/emaillogo.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
content.Add(fileStream, "inline", "logo.png");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.mailgun.net/v2/" + DOMAIN + "/messages", content);
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, helped me big time!

Comment: this works for me, Thanks!! but one thing... message should be like <div>Inline image here: <img src="cid:logo.png"></div> see this more more info https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#sending-via-api